# Implementing Output audio panning with Naudio

Tags: .net, naudio

I have an application where I am receiving RAW wave array from network and playing out it.
Basic code is something like this

```
...
private WaveOut waveOut;
private BufferedWaveProvider waveProvider;
private WaveFormat waveformat = new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 2);
private VolumeWaveProvider16 volumeProvider;
....
....
waveOut = new WaveOut();
waveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(waveformat);
volumeProvider = new VolumeWaveProvider16(waveProvider);
volumeProvider.Volume = volumeSlider.Volume;
waveProvider.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(200);
...
...
byte[] byteBuffer = udpListener.Receive(ref endPoint);
waveProvider.AddSamples(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);
...
...
waveOut.Play();
...
```

I need to implement panning functionality, play only from left or right speaker according to user control:
Which NAudio component should I use to achieve this functionality?

(Have foud some examples but they use WaveChannel32 which I cant integrate with my example)
Any help or hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest approach is for you to convert to an `ISampleProvider` as soon as possible. The `ToSampleProvider` extension method does this for you. Then you can pass it into `PanningSampleProvider`. You could also put `VolumeSampleProvider` into your signal chain. You can play sample providers directly, or convert back to 16 bit with a `SampleToWaveProvider16`

So the code would be something like this:

```
var waveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(waveformat);
var volumeProvider = new VolumeSampleProvider(waveProvider.ToSampleProvider());
var panProvider = new PanningSampleProvider(volumeProvider);
panProvider.Pan = 1.0f; // pan 100% right

waveOut.Init(panProvider);
waveOut.Play();
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thank You for replay. But I am geting exception {"Source sample provider must be mono"}. I give a look, there is code inside class PanningSampleProvider if (source.WaveFormat.Channels != 1) { throw new ArgumentException("Source sample provider must be mono"); } How I can fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: so your audio is stereo then? panning usually turns mono to stereo. I'd make a very simple alternative to VolumeSampleProvider that had a left and right volume property in that case.

Comment: Yes, my audio is stereo.
There is no something similar to WaveChannel32?
I have found some example, but it is not works for me.

WaveStream Reader =  CreateReaderStream(fileName);
_volumeStream =   new WaveChannel32(Reader);
_volumeStream.Pan =1.0f;

So you mean to create some new class like VolumeSampleProvider which will have left and right properties? Where I can take a look for some example?
I am totally new in this area, sorry if my questions are trivial.