# Simple alternative to VolumeSampleProvider that will have a left and right volume property

Tags: visual-studio, naudio

when playing trying to play audio in a chat application that I'm making I got the exception {"Source sample provider must be mono"}  in this line  var panProvider = new PanningSampleProvider(volumeProvider);
Code:

```
 private void ReceiveUdpMessage(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] bytesRead = UDPc.EndReceive(ar, ref ep);
                var waveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 2));
                waveProvider.DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true;
                waveProvider.AddSamples(bytesRead, 0, bytesRead.Length);
                var volumeProvider = new VolumeSampleProvider(waveProvider.ToSampleProvider());
                var panProvider = new PanningSampleProvider(volumeProvider);
                
                mixer.AddMixerInput(panProvider);
                UDPc.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveUdpMessage), null);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
       UDPc.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveUdpMessage), null);


        }
```

I saw this answer [Implementing Output audio panning with Naudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157003/implementing-output-audio-panning-with-naudio)
but when mark answered in the comments:"I'd make a very simple alternative to VolumeSampleProvider that had a left and right volume property in that case".
he didn't elaborate and I'm new to this so have no idea what to do from here.
Does someone know what I'm supposed to do?
Thx